# Minimum Wavelength of x-rays

Tags: wavelength, x-rays

So in an x-ray tube a small percentage of the kinetic energy of the accelerated electrons gets converted into x rays. Why then, is the minimum wavelength of the x rays equal to the maximum kinetic energy of the electrons?

Comment: Would you expect to get higher x-ray energy out than what you put in as the energy of the electrons?

Answer (score 2):

The reason is quite simple I guess:

The highest possible photon energy can be reached if an electron transfers its whole kinetic energy into photon energy:

> $$h\nu = E_{max}$$

According to the Duane-Hunt law, the maximum energy of the photon implies also
the smallest wavelength that can be reached:

> $$h\nu = eU$$
>
> $$\lambda_{min} = \frac{hc}{eU}$$

with

> $$\lambda = \frac{c}{\nu}$$

where:

> $\lambda_{min}$: minimum wavelength
> $e$: unit load
> $U$: excitation voltage
> $c$: speed of light
> $h$: Planck’s constant
> $\nu$: frequency

In summary the whole point is that the kinetic energy is inversely proportional to the wavelength.

Answer (score 1):

[How do you make X-rays?](http://science.howstuffworks.com/x-ray2.htm) The electron beam interacts with the target, usually a metal plate which often doubles as the anode of the electron gun, and some of the electron energy is transformed into x-rays.

[X-rays are a category of electromagnetic radiation](http://science.hq.nasa.gov/kids/imagers/ems/xrays.html) which can be defined either in terms of their wavelength/energy, or historically, by their mode of production. Weak x-rays blend into the strong UV spectrum, while strong x-rays blend into the gamma ray spectrum.

The typical x-ray corresponds to the energy of transition from the outer (weakly bound) electron shells to the inner (strongly bound) electron shells. As you study the binding energies of the inner shell electrons of the periodic table you will find that the binding energy increases with the atomic number.  The electrons in the beam exchange energy with the material in several ways: they may shed a portion of their energy, ionizing the atoms, or they may knock out inner electrons.

In the typical design the accelerating voltage is matched with the binding energy of the inner electrons of the target material, with a little extra for engineering losses; this will result in [x-ray emission at the characteristic energy](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/quantum/xrayc.html) for that material, which appears as energy peaks in the x-ray spectrum.

The [weaker x-rays, called bremsstrahlung, or braking radiation](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/quantum/xrayc.html#c2) is often blocked by insertion of a second metal plate, with a lower atomic number, to act as a filter. If properly chosen it will be transparent to the characteristic x-rays of the first plate, but strongly absorbing for the lower-energy x-rays.

Thus in a well-designed x-ray generator the operating voltage determines the energy of the x-rays, though the choice of target materials plays a major role.

Answer (score 0):

A min wavelength has more energy than a max wavelength so an electron with higher kinetic will produce a shorter wavelength.

Answer (score 0):

X rays are produced when fast moving electrons(i.e., energetic, accelerated through a large potential difference) hit a metal target. In this process, some of the energy of the electrons out of  $\mathrm{ \ eV}$ (where V = voltage through which they are accelerated) is converted into the photon energy of the X rays. Maximum frequency of the X rays produced can be reached if whole of the kinetic energy of the electrons is converted into the energy of the photons of the X rays.

That is,

$\mathrm{eV = h\nu_{max}}$

$\mathrm{\nu_{max}=\frac{eV}{h}}$

we know,

$\mathrm{c = \nu \lambda}$

which shows frequency is inversely proportional to wavelength. So, if we know the maximum frequency, minimum wavelength can be determined using this equation.